# JS имитация нажатия на кнопку если нет блока <form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как сделать имитацию нажатия на кнопку <a href="" id="submit", но только в том случаем если в блоке не присутствует формы
То есть, если в блоке myblock - нет никакой формы, через 3 сек, происходит автонажатие по <a href="" id=""submit

Пример:

```html
<a href="" id="submit">имитация</a>

<div class="myblock">
  <form>
    < form >
    форма которой как бы нет
    < / form >
  </form>
</div>
```

Как делать данное действие?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="" id="submit">имитация</a>

<body>
    <div class="myblock">
        <form>
            <form name="myform">
                <input type="text">
                <button id="btn">submit</button>
            </form>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let form = document.forms[0];
        form.submit();
    })
</script>
```

Вместо нажатия на кнопку может быть любое другое событие.